# how to pass variable to python request for the target

Tags: python, elasticsearch, curl, python-requests

I have a data populated for an exclude put curl request to Elastic and it works fine with specifying ip address in my request like below.

`data = '{\n "transient" : {\n "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip" : "172.39.1.23"\n }\n}'`

I just want to be able to put a variable in stead of ip address and it is not working. I have instip variable set to same string in my python.

`data = '{ "transient" : { "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip": instip} }'`

but it doesn't like it!

any help appreciated!

-fatdragon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
data = f'{{ "transient" : {{ "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip": "{instip}"}} }}'
```

Comment: data = '{ "transient" : { "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip": "{instip}" } }'
gives 400
if I put IP string , I get 200 response.
I think the f you have there is a typo , do you also have extra brackets in your comment!?

Comment: It is difficult to say what is the issue without seeing your code. `f` in front of the string is not a typo, and if you removed it, it can be a source of the problem. This `f` indicates a [formatted string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings).  In a formatted string double curly braces `{{...}}` represent single curly braces.

Comment: bb1- I put what you suggested and I got 200 response. testing some more.. Thank you!